# How to replace string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a string which is like

```
var test="clientNumber=123,TestSubject=Tom";
```

I need to replace `Tom with Mary`. `Tom` is entered by the user and could be anything but i need to make it `Mary` while processing . Also `clientNumber` & `TestSubject` could be in any order in the string.

Thanks

Comment: Do you specifically need to replace `TestSubject=Tom` with `TestSubject=Mary`, or do you need to replace any occurrence of `Tom` with `Mary`?

Comment: just hard code it, and forget about it.

Comment: I would split the string by the `,` so that there is an array. Find out which one contains TestSubject and use a regex that find the string that matches that and replace it with `TestSubject=Mary`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to want to use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), for example

```
test = test.replace(/(TestSubject=)[^,]*/, '$1Mary')
```

The code I give replaces everything between `"TestSubject="` and the end of string or the next comma.

This changes

`"clientNumber=123,TestSubject=Tom"` into `"clientNumber=123,TestSubject=Mary"`

and

`"TestSubject=Tom,clientNumber=123"` into `"TestSubject=Mary,clientNumber=123"`